# How to use "for some reason" in a sentence?

Tags: idioms, expressions

Some examples (right or wrong, I do not know)

- He went to the store--for some reason.
- He went to the store, for some reason.
- For some reason, she went to the store.

A grammatical explanation as to what exactly "for what reason" is would be great too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use either

> For some reason, he went to the store.

or

> He went to the store, for some reason.

"For some reason" means that the speaker is unsure why the action has occurred.

It is advisable to use a comma here because otherwise its meaning could be ambiguous; you might think he went to the store precisely to *find* some kind of reason.

Comment: Presumably, one would to a university to obtain some reason.

Comment: @Malvolio, it's so cute that you think that *reason* is what universities dispense.

Comment: @JSBangs -- well, it may not be what they're actually dispensing, but it's what their customers are seeking.

Comment: @Malvolio. That, and beer. And sex.

Comment: @JSBangs -- if I don't order the beer, can I substitute two helpings of sex instead?

Comment: @Malvolio: I think you have the exchange rate totally mixed up. It's quite the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

"for some reason" is a prepositional phrase.